# How to combine multiple rows into 1 row in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am having trouble combining multiple rows into 1 row, below is my current data:

[image: Data]

I want one row of symptoms for each VAERS_ID. However, because the number of rows each VAERS_ID  is inconsistent, I am having trouble.

I have tried this:

```
test= data %>% 
select(VAERS_ID, SYMPTOM1, SYMPTOM2, SYMPTOM3, SYPMTOM4, SYMPTOM5) %>% 
group_by(VAERS_ID) %>% 
mutate(Grp = paste0(SYMPTOM1,SYMPTOM1, SYMPTOM2, SYMPTOM3, SYPMTOM4, SYMPTOM5, collapse 
= ",")) %>% 
distinct(VAERS_ID, Grp, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

This gives me the original data, plus another column labeled Grp containing all of the symptoms for each VAERS_ID pasted together, with a comma between each set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your data in a copy-pasteable format instead of as an image. One of the best ways to do this is by adding to your question the output of `dput(data)`. Then we can help you with your problem.

Comment: Are you looking for tidyr::pivot_wider?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems right but since data cannot be copied and tested, I am not able to reproduce your error. Some changes suggested, which you can try.

since you want "ALL Symptoms" in 1 place for each VAERS_ID, which is a common real world use case and I face this often. If you don't need original data in output, simply use this

```
data%>%
group_by(VAERS_ID) %>%
summarise("Symptoms" = paste0(SYMPTOM1,SYMPTOM1, SYMPTOM2, SYMPTOM3, SYPMTOM4, SYMPTOM5, collapse = ",")
```

With `mutate` you get original data since it adds a new column.

To address the warning to ungroup, just added `%>%ungroup` at end or within summarise add `.groups="drop"`